# Calculating $\lim_{x\to 0} \left[\frac{1}{\sin^2x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, fractions

How can I calculate this limit?
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left[\frac{1}{\sin^2x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right] = \,?$$

I don't have any idea how to do it.

Comment: 10 bucks says that this was assigned homework from a section on L'Hospital's rule............

Comment: no , and it's not working here..

Comment: @user296602 No bet.  I need that ten dollars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{1}{\sin^2x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^3}\cdot\frac{1+\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}{\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}}\right)=$$
$$=2\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos{x}}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{3\cdot\frac{x^2}{4}}=\frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: can you explain how?

Comment: A thrown up line is a trademark, too.

Comment: Seriously? This has to be a record for non-transparent algebra mixed with lack of explanation.

Comment: @MathQues I added something. See now.

Comment: Correct  and without Taylor (+1).

Comment: I honestly don't understand why this answer has received so much hate. It's written clearly, yet leaves at least *something* for the OP to do... +$1$ for this answer.

Comment: This answer could break a record, at least a temporary one, of being the *accepted answer* (by the OP) with the most downvotes...

Comment: @Clayton I mildly like this answer as leaving something for the OP to complete, though the other two answers **also** leave something to check: that the Taylor developments are correct and etc. Such an answer as this one, in an exam, I would take off quite some points **if it is not more explained** (for example, the use of both arithmetic of limits and L'Hospital at the same time...and their justifications).

Comment: +1 @MichaelRozenberg   I have never seen an accepted answer with a negative score lol   first time I see this

Comment: @DonAntonio: Absolutely! As the answer for an exam I would take probably half of the credit away. As an answer to a PSQ, this seems more than reasonable an answer, though. :)

Answer (score 6):

Note that

$$\sin^2 x=\left(x-\frac{x^3}6+o(x^3)\right)^2=x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+o(x^4)$$

$$\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}-\frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{x^2-\sin x^2}{x^2\sin x^2}=\frac{x^2-x^2+\frac{x^4}{3}+o(x^4)}{x^4+o(x^4)}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}+o(1)}{1+o(1)}\to \frac13$$

Comment: I think this is the clearest, simplest answer here. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks a lot for your kind appreciation!

Comment: (+1) Perhaps you should explain how the expansion of $\sin^2x$ is obtained.

Comment: @Bernard Yes of course, it is better to specify this step! Thanks

Comment: In the first parentheses in the first line it must be $\;\mathcal O(x^6)\;$ , and in the denominator in the second line it must be the same.

Comment: @DonAntonio I use little-o notation!

Comment: @gimusi Oh, I see. Well, that's slightly odd in this case, I think...but I guess it's fine.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think it's just a matter of habit, I'm used to it!

Answer (score 5):

The numerator is
$$(x+\sin (x))(x-\sin (x))\sim 2x\cdot\frac {x^3}{6} $$

the denominator is
$$x^2\sin^2 (x)\sim x^4$$

the result is $ \frac {1}{3}. $

Comment: +1 even I do nnot share that Taylor obsession of yours ....