# Evaluating a Limit (without L'Hopital's rule)

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I just got this limit problem. It is easy but there is an instruction to solve this limit without L'Hopital's rule. How can I derived this?

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} + \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)} - \frac{2}{x^2}\right)$$

Comment: Can you use the (derivative of the) [partial fraction expansion of $\cot$](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_Expansion_for_Cotangent_Function)?

Comment: After replacing $\cos^2x$ by $1-\sin^2x,$ this answers your question:  [Calculating $\lim_{x\to 0} \left[\frac{1}{\sin^2x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2657579/calculating-lim-x-to-0-left-frac1-sin2x-frac1x2-right)

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal L &=& \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac1{\sin^2x} + \frac{\cos^2x}{\sin^2x}-\frac2{x^2}\right)=\\
&=&\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac2{\sin^2x}-1-\frac2{x^2}\right)=\\
&=& 2\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x^2-\sin^2x}{x^2\sin^2x}\right)-1=\\
&=&2\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x^2-\sin^2x}{x^4}\right)-1=\\
&=&2\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x+\sin x}{x}\cdot\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\right)-1=\\
&=& 4\underbrace{\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\right)}_{\mathcal{L_1}}-1.
\end{eqnarray}
There are nice ways to find
$$\mathcal L_1 = \frac16,$$
such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1077642). Hence $\mathcal L = -\frac13$.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} + \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin^2(x)} - \frac{2}{x^2}\right)&=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac {x^2+x^2\cos^2x-2\sin^2x}{x^2\sin^2x} \right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac {2x^2-x^2\sin^2x-2\sin^2x}{x^2\sin^2x} \right)\\
&=-1+\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac {2(x-\sin x)(x+\sin x)}{x^2\sin^2x} \right)\\
&=-1+\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac {2(x-(x-\frac{x^3}6+O(x^5)))(x+x+O(x^3))}{x^2(x+O(x^3))^2} \right)\\
&=-1+\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{(\frac{x^3}3+O(x^5))(2x+O(x^3))}{x^4+O(x^6)} \right)\\
&=-1+\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\frac23x^4+O(x^6)}{x^4+O(x^6)} \right)\\
&=-1+\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\frac23+O(x^2)}{1+O(x^2)} \right)\\
&=-1+\frac23\\
&=-\frac13
\end{align}$